# python function variable in text

Tags: python, function, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a simple python function that looks like:

```
def fnc_assign(y,a): 
    'new_acc_no' + y + '.text' = import_list[x][a]
```

What I want to do with it is to assign new_acc_no10.text = import_list[1][0] when I call fnc_assign(10,1) but I'm stuck on getting the left hand side of the function to work (I get a SyntaxError: can't assign to operator).

Thanks for your help!

edit: 
As mentioned below, new_acc_no1 has a property .text that = import_list[x][0].

I have a lot of new_acc_no's so what I have been doing is:

```
new_acc_no1.text = import_list[x][0]
new_acc_no2.text = import_list[x][1]
new_acc_no3.text = import_list[x][2]
new_acc_no4.text = import_list[x][12]
new_acc_no5.text = import_list[x][13]
```

And I still have a lot more that I need to add so I thought writing a function that can write out new_acc_noY.text = import_list[x][a] would be beneficial with x being the variable in a while loop that the previous code block is in. So the function would be fnc_assign(1,2) and it will generate the output:

```
new_acc_no1.text = import_list[x][2]
```

with x still taking in the variable input from the loop its in. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically create a variable name? Also, you can't have a period in a variable name in Python.

Comment: Is `.text` supposed to be a property of `new_acc_no<y>`? Because if so, you need to go about this in a whole different way.

Comment: Yeah it's a property, please see post edit for additional info

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
def fnc_assign(y,x): 
    import_list[x][0] = 'new_acc_no' + y + '.text'
```

Note that your LHS is a string, and strings in Python are immutable, i.e. cannot be changed. I understood your intent is to assign the resulting string into the array element in question which you put on the RHS. Just reversing them does the assignment.

Or is your intent to actually have a variable named `new_acc_no10.text` and assign to it the value in the import list?

**UPDATE**

This also assumes `y` is a string (or supports concatenation with strings using the `+` operator), if not, use `str(y)` instead.

---

**NEW TASK UPDATE**

Your code in the question (assuming an outer loop in `x`

```
for x in someValueIterator:
    new_acc_no1.text = import_list[x][0]
    new_acc_no2.text = import_list[x][1]
    new_acc_no3.text = import_list[x][2]
    new_acc_no4.text = import_list[x][12]
    new_acc_no5.text = import_list[x][13]
```

seems to suggest the following approach. Organize the account numbers into a dictionary, indexed by the RHS index you are using to assign, i.e. something like

```
acc_nos = [new_acc_no1, new_acc_no2, new_acc_no3, new_acc_no4, new_acc_no5]
indices = [0,1,2,12,13]
idx2acc = dict(zip(indices, acc_nos))
```

and now loop like this:

```
for index, acc_no in idx2acc.iteritems():
    acc_no.text = import_list[x][index]
```

and taking into account the outer loop in `x`, instead of

```
for x in someValueIterator:
    for index, acc_no in idx2acc.iteritems():
        acc_no.text = import_list[x][index]
```

consider looping like so directly:

```
for current_list in import_list:
    for index, acc_no in idx2acc.iteritems():
        acc_no.text = current_list[index]
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, it seems like I may have misjudged the issue, .text is a property of the new_acc_no

Answer (score 0):

change y to `str(y)`

```
def fnc_assign(y,x): 
    import_list[x][0] = 'new_acc_no' + str(y) + '.text'
```

edit:

you can't add int to str.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.